# Ubuntu 22.04 installation along with KVM - offline installation

Tags: 22.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

In Ubuntu 16.04 we have an option to install kernel virtual machine during OS installation, but in Ubuntu 22.04, what's the option available to install KVM?

I need to install virsh KVM on top of Ubuntu 22.04 with the initial OS installation itself, as there's no internet available to the server.

Comment: Any update would be appreciated, I need to setup VM. Else have to go with older versions 16 already tested and working

Comment: I first wanted to tell you how to get packages from the disk, but really that would not get you updates and hence seems wrong. You could (on a different computer with internet) prepare an offline repo following https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/Repository and once you are happy with it put that on a ISO (or whatever else you use to get things onto the system). That would give you the latest versions, and you should have that for updates in general - not just to get KVM installed. WDYT?